# debugging with PHPeclipse

Tags: php, phpeclipse

I am trying to set-up Eclipse 3.7 with PHPeclipse. While trying to use the debugger (debug perspective) 
it says:
Could not open input file: test.php

I am using php dbg script.in the configuration option i have given the full path of the test file.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because the debugger cannot match the real path of the file and the path in your project.

In the debug configuration, there is an screen to edit filemap, you should start working on that.

this [tutorial](http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Howto/XDebugAndPHPEclipse) show how to do it.